# Getting a random object from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, random

First and foremost, forgive me if my language is off - I'm still learning how to both speak and write in programming languages. How I can retrieve an entire object from an array in PHP when that array has several key, value pairs?

```
<?php

  $quotes = array();
  $quotes[0] = array(
    "quote" => "This is a great quote",
    "attribution" => "Benjamin Franklin"
  );
  $quotes[1] = array(
    "quote" => "This here is a really good quote",
    "attribution" => "Theodore Roosevelt"
  );

function get_random_quote($quote_id, $quote) {

  $output = "";
  $output = '<h1>' . $quote["quote"] . '.</h1>';
  $output .= '<p>' . $quote["attribution"] . '</p>';

  return $output;
} ?>

<?php 
  foreach($quotes as $quote_id => $quote) {
  echo get_random_quote($quote_id, $quote); 
} ?>
```

Using array_rand and var_dump I'm able to view the item in the browser in raw form, but I'm unable to actually figure out how to get each element to display in HTML.

```
$quote = $quotes;
$random_quote = array_rand($quote);
var_dump($quote[$random_quote]);
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The preferred output would be to display one quote at random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for that hefty function

```
$random=$quotes[array_rand($quotes)]; 
echo $random["quote"];
echo $random["attribution"];
```

Also, this is useless

```
<?php 
  foreach($quotes as $quote_id => $quote) {
  echo get_random_quote($quote_id, $quote); 
} ?>
```

If you have to run a loop over all the elements then why randomize hem in the first place? This is circular. You should just run the loop as many number of times as the quotes you need in output. If you however just need all the quotes but in a random order then that can simply be done in one line.

```
shuffle($quotes);            // this will randomize your quotes order for loop
foreach($quotes as $qoute)
{
   echo $quote["quote"];
   echo $quote["attribution"];
}
```

This will also make sure that your quotes are not repeated, whereas your own solution and the other suggestions will still repeat your quotes randomly for any reasonably sized array of quotes.

A simpler version of your function would be

```
function get_random_quote(&$quotes)
 {
  $quote=$quotes[array_rand($quotes)]; 
  return <<<HTML
            <h1>{$quote["quote"]}</h1>
            <p>{$quote["attribution"]}</p>
HTML;
}
```

Comment: Won't the shuffle function display all the quotes? Sorry for not being clearer, but ultimately I'd like to display only one quote, and then ultimately have a link that would generate another random quote within the same code block replacing the original.

Comment: Yes that will display all the quotes but then your own solution was doing that incorrectly as well. If you just need one random quote each time then just use the first 3 lines of this answer

Comment: Thanks Hanky Panky, that's exactly what I was looking for - you rock! Much appreciated :) If I did want to grab the ID to append to the URL, how would I grab the ID of the quote?

Comment: I guess I could just add that as a key, value pair?

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood you last question. You could return the id as well as your html from the function in an array. Or you could return the object itself and format it where you call it. That way you will get the id too

Comment: If you cant make it work, ill write it up for you but first try it yourself so you can learn more :)

Comment: Fair enough! ;) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

function should be like this

```
function get_random_quote($quote_id, $quote) {

  $m = 0;
  $n = sizeof($quote)-1;

  $i= rand($m, $n); 
  $output = "";
  $output = '<h1>' . $quote[$i]["quote"] . '.</h1>';
  $output .= '<p>' . $quote[$i]["attribution"] . '</p>';

  return $output;
}
```

However you are not using your first parameter-`$quote_id` in the function. you can remove it. and call function with single parameter that is array `$quote`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this:

```
$quote = $quotes;
$random_quote = array_rand($quote);
$random = $quote[$random_quote];
echo '<h1>' . $random["quote"] . '.</h1><br>';
echo '<p>' . $random["attribution"] . '</p>';
```

**Want to create a function:**

```
echo get_random_quote($quotes); 

function get_random_quote($quotes) {
    $quote = $quotes;
    $random_quote = array_rand($quote);
    $random = $quote[$random_quote];
    return '<h1>' . $random["quote"] . '.</h1><br>'.'<p>' . $random["attribution"] . '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you dont need the `$quote_id` in `get_random_quote()`, should be like this:

```
function get_random_quote($quote) {

  $output = "";
  $output = '<h1>' . $quote["quote"] . '.</h1>';
  $output .= '<p>' . $quote["attribution"] . '</p>';

  return $output;
}
```

And I cant see anything random that the function is doing. You are just iterating through the array:

```
foreach($quotes as $quote_id => $quote) {
  echo get_random_quote( $quote); 
}
```

According to  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php:

> `array_rand()` Picks one or more random entries out of an array, and
>   returns the key (or keys) of the random entries.

So I guess `$quote[$random_quote]` should return your element, you can use it like:

```
$random_quote = array_rand($quotes);
echo get_random_quote($quote[$random_quote]);
```